# how to wrap a java.net.URL in jsoup?

Tags: java, cookies, jsoup

Jsoup.connect accept a string URL as parameter. How let Jsoup connect accept a java.net.URL.

The use case is as following: The url (someurl/getimg) returns an img which is validation code, and it will also set the cookie. Since Jsoup can't read img, so I use java.net.URL and then openStream() to save the image, but I also want re-use the connection. Since the cookie is set at session level, and I want to use jsoup to do automate web. If I just use

```
 Jsoup.connect("someurl/login")
```

it will kick off a new connection, since it's a new connect, the session level cookie from the img will be expired.

Basically I want to use java.net.URL to access the image from someurl/getimg, get the text from the image,  and then fill the text in the image as validation code to login in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
Node node = wrap("someurl/login");
```

And that's it!